# Geometry Nodes - Position/Placement of CurveToMesh from extracted Curves

Tags: modeling, geometry-nodes

I want to replace faces of an existing object to gain control over resolution (subdivisions). I extract edges and convert them into curves and create a mesh from these. Unfortunately placement/position of the resulting mesh is off. All transformations are applied! How can I fix that?
Here is the model:
[image]
Here is the nodetree:
[image]

Here is the Blend:
https://www.mediafire.com/file/vksh10k0hz495l5/blenderSkyScraper_proc-e.blend/file

Comment: Can you share the file on blend-exchange.com? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This misunderstanding is perfectly normal, and it happens often:

When using the `Mesh to Curve` node, the profile is used relative to the position and normals of the curve along which you create the mesh.

This means:

You would have to use a curve as the profile, positioned starting from $(0,0,0)$.

You can solve this as follows:

[image]

Instead of using the profile curve you extracted, I create another curve that starts at $(0,0,0)$ but is exactly as long. The direction of the curve is also crucial here. This is used starting from the normals of the points of your curve along which you create the profile. For example, if you change the tilt of the main curve, you also change the direction.

*PS: If you are using Blender 3.3, then you should apply the node `Transfer Attribute` instead of `Sample Index`.*

[image]
<sub>*(Blender 3.4)*</sub>